# TS Error: Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type '[T]'. Property '0' is missing in type 'T[]'

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between T[] and [T] in typescript?

Consider the following typescript code:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

const foo: Foo = { bar: 'bar' };
const anotherFoo: Foo = { ...foo };

let fooArray1: Foo[] = [foo];
fooArray1 = [...fooArray1, anotherFoo]; // works

let fooArray2: [Foo] = [foo];
fooArray2 = [...fooArray2, anotherFoo]; // error: Type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to type '[Foo]'. Property '0' is missing in type 'Foo[]'.
```

- When using the `Foo[]` syntax, the array can be replaced by a new one of the same type using the spread operator for array destructuring.
- When using the `[Foo]` syntax, however, it throws an error: **Type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to type '[Foo]'. Property '0' is missing in type 'Foo[]'**

Why is that? It's especially confusing since both would compile to the very same js code:

```
// Foo[] notation    
var fooArray1 = [foo];
fooArray1 = fooArray1.concat([anotherFoo]);

// [Foo] notation (throws ts error)
var fooArray2 = [foo];
fooArray2 = fooArray2.concat([anotherFoo]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T[]` is an Array, meaning it can be of arbitrary length. `[T]` is a tuple type, it's similar to an array (at runtime they are arrays) but it can only have one element of type `T`. Tuples have a fixed number of elements, and positions matter:

```
let t1: [number, string] = [1, 'a'] //ok 
let t2: [number, string] = ['a', 1] // error invalid types 
let t3: [number, string] = [1, 'a', 'b'] // error too big
```

For more information see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)